# iOS send JSON array in POST

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I want to create a JSON array of the following structure:

```
"Create Account":{ 
"RegistryNumber":"",
"People":[{
"PeopleId":"",
"email":"",
"pass":"",
}]
}
```

I am using the folllowing code to do it:

```
NSDictionary *content0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"PeopleId", @"0",
                              @"email", @"email",
                              @"pass", @"pass",nil];

  NSArray *peopledetails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:content0,nil];
NSMutableDictionary *peopleDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[peopleDict setObject:@"content0" forKey:@"People"];
  
NSMutableDictionary *details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  
[details setObject:@"RegistryNumber" forKey:@"RegistryNumber"];
[details setObject:@"peopleDict" forKey:@"People"];
NSMutableDictionary *MainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[MainDict setObject:@"details" forKey:@"Create Account"];
```

But this gives me an error from the server. I have other API which works fine when array is not in picture.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
[peopleDict setObject:@"content0" forKey:@"People"];
```

to

```
[peopleDict setObject:peopledetails forKey:@"People"];
```

Remove all @"" for objects.

`@"details"` is a string and `details` is an object

Or here is the simple way

```
  NSDictionary *dict=@{
                         @"Create Account": @{
                                 @"RegistryNumber": @"",
                                 @"People": @[
                                         @{
                                             @"PeopleId": @"",
                                             @"Email": @"",
                                             @"pass":@""
                                             }
                                         ]
                                 }
                         };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)simpleJsonParsing
{
    //  URL request with server
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //-- Get request and response though URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    //-- JSON Parsing
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);

    for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in result)
    {
         NSString *string = dic[@"Create Account"];
        if (string)
        {
             NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             dic[@"Create Account"] = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"Error in response");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong structure

```
NSDictionary *content0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"PeopleId", @"0",
                              @"email", @"email",
                              @"pass", @"pass",nil];


postDict = @{@"Create Account":@{@"RegistryNumber":"","People":content0}}
```

now convert this into jason and send to your server